# Will another account on my PC have access to any of my files?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

If I create another account on my PC for someone else, will they have access to any of my files or folders e.g. Dropbox etc?

Or is EVERYTHING (apart from installed programs) hidden from them?

Thanks!

Comment: This entirely depends on the permissions you provide the user profile.  The only thing the user won't have access to is your current user profile by default, unless, they are in the Administrator user group.

Answer (score 1):

If the second user is a standard user, and your account is password protected, they will be unable to access anything you save under "c:/users/youruser" (which includes my documents, videos, music, downloads etc.) by default unless you change their permissions. They will still be able to access program files etc. If they try to access your files a box will pop up asking for an administrators password, same for when they try to install a program. If you want them to be able to access your files either change their permissions which is done by right clicking on the folder you want them to access and clicking on properties, or by simply making them an administrator, which will give them all the same permissions that you have